# Mechanize - Fill form with square brackets in input name

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to fill a form with Mechanize. It works but some of the input name have [] inside and it fails.

```
<input id="titleen_US" type="text" name="title[en_US]" value="">
```

I tried

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://myurl.com")
first_form = page.form('item')
first_form.title[en_US] = 'This is my title'
```

But i have `undefined method 'title='`.
 Any idea? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Following.

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://myurl.com")
first_form = page.form('item')

title_field = first_form.field_with(:name => "title[en_US]")
title_field.value = "whatever_title"
```

OR

```
a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get("http://myurl.com")
first_form = page.form('item')

first_form['title[en_US]'] = "title"
```